# Is there any benefit of working on string directly rather than assigning it to a var?

Tags: c#, string, memory-leaks

Is there any benefit of doing this;

```
private void Method()
{
    var data = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Data"].Split('-');
}
```

than doing this;

```
private void Method()
{
    var _data = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Data"];
    var data = _data.Split('-');
}
```

Case: I need to read bunch of configuration values like this in the same method, **multiple** times (let's say every time I instantiate this class).

How will both cases will affect the performance and memory? Or are they pretty much the same things? I see assigning it to a variable will allocate space on memory for no reason.

Comment: They effectily are equal, in both cases you´re doing exactly the same. But even *if* there were any difference it was so little that you shouldn´t bother about it. You should however concentrate on the code being readable and understandable.

Comment: The second approach would make help you add additional validation checks like, if ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Data"] is null, then the first would fail, in the second, you can always check for _data is not null

Comment: Also, 2nd approach lets you more easily see the interim result in the debugger.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, not needed ,,, rather use quick watch window while debugging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will reduce those to the exact same thing. No, there's no difference *in this scenario*. If you're ever curious, compile it in release mode, and use `ildasm` to look at what it did.

However! Performance questions should never be answered by hunch - or even *asked* on hunch. First, determine if you are actually trying to solve a real problem - otherwise you're probably just yak shaving.

Comment: Personally, I sometimes introduce "artifical" variables to make debugging and inspecting values easier.

Comment: @UweKeim Or just to increase the understanding of the code.

Answer (score 3):

There will be the same IL code generated in both cases.

And don't forget about [The Rules of Code Optimization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/audiofool/2007/06/14/the-rules-of-code-optimization/)

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are equal. You have a false understanding on when space on your memory is allocated. This actually happens inside the `AppSettings`-call, not on assignement. Thus when you make any call to a member the result allready *exists* on memory. Storing this value in a variable does not increase anything - neither memory-allocation nor performance.

However if you´d store the result in a member of your class it´ll be garbage-collected far later than your local `data`-variable as it doesn´t get out of scope. In this case storing your result to the member will allocate memory as long as the instance exists.

Having said this it is in mostly all cases more important to focus on your code being maintainable, that is if other developers can understand it without asking what all this about.

This means you shouldn´t ask: [which horse runs faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) but instead which code is easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

In your first case since `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Data"]` will return a `string` there is no harm in chaining the `Split()` method with it than creating a extra variable.

In second case, it would be efficient if  `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Data"]` would be used multiple places. In such case, instead of fetching it again and again, you fetch it once, store it to a variable and re-use it.